# Algorithm for fitting text into an irregular shape

Tags: algorithm, text

I'm sure this is already answered somewhere, but I just don't know the correct terminology to search for.

Context: I'm developing some code to generate a PDF that is using a fairly low-level library. So I'm having to write some basic text layout and fitting routines that will break on word boundaries and fit the text within defined constraints (e.g., in a column or around a fixed block).

I'd like to a find a reasonably efficient approach for fitting text around an arbitrary shape; eg something like this:

[image: text inside a shape]

(This example was taken from this blog post: http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/11098565269/text-wrap-with-core-text,  that was an answer to this question:  [Rendering CoreText within an irregular shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158012/rendering-coretext-within-an-irregular-shape))

I'm guessing I need to break the text down into a series of boxes and it then becomes a geometry problem of fitting boxes into the shape, but I'm struggling to find good explanations of suitable algorithms or approaches for this.  Delving into browser engine layout code to see how they do it is a case of getting lost in all the detail.

Comment: Is your question different from this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048305/algorithm-for-text-wrapping-within-a-shape?rq=1

Comment: Looks like that question is more or less what I'm asking, yes.  Although I was also hoping someone could recommend some good books or online resources that cover this sort of thing.

Comment: And this blog post: This blog post:  http://hansmuller-webkit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/horizontal-box-polygon-intersection-for.html   is almost exactly what I was looking for; it explains the process of scanning down a shape, determining available width, and fitting rectangles within the shape.